# Order command output using line field

Tags: linux, sorting, command-line, terminal, pipeline

I want to order some command output (using pipeline), taking into account some field from the output.

For example, if I run `l` command, I have:

```
-rw-r-----  1 matias matias  67843408 sep 11 08:55 file1
-rw-r-----  1 matias matias      1952 oct 23 12:05 file2
-rw-r-----  1 matias matias       965 oct 23 10:14 asd.txt
-rw-r-----  1 matias matias    892743 sep  3 08:36 aaa.txt
-rw-r-----  1 matias matias    892743 ago 18 08:09 qwe
```

I want to order this output according for example by the day of the month field, so the output should be:

```
-rw-r-----  1 matias matias    892743 sep  3 08:36 aaa.txt
-rw-r-----  1 matias matias  67843408 sep 11 08:55 file1
-rw-r-----  1 matias matias    892743 ago 18 08:09 qwe
-rw-r-----  1 matias matias      1952 oct 23 12:05 file2
-rw-r-----  1 matias matias       965 oct 23 10:14 asd.txt
```

How can I do this? I usually use `grep`, `cat`, `l`, `ls`, `ll`, but I can't figure out how to achieve this.

Comment: `ls` can do some sorting on its own, but not that particular (weird) one. However, [don't parse `ls`!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `sort` with the 7th column:

```
$ sort -k7 -n file
-rw-r-----  1 matias matias    892743 sep  3 08:36 aaa.txt
-rw-r-----  1 matias matias  67843408 sep 11 08:55 file1
-rw-r-----  1 matias matias    892743 ago 18 08:09 qwe
-rw-r-----  1 matias matias      1952 oct 23 12:05 file2
-rw-r-----  1 matias matias       965 oct 23 10:14 asd.txt
```

From `man sort`:

```
  -n, --numeric-sort
          compare according to string numerical value

   -k, --key=KEYDEF
          sort via a key; KEYDEF gives location and type
```

However, this is quite fragile and, in general, [you should not parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score -1):

use `ls -t` or `ls -tr`

You can google this

Comment: no, this wouldn't show the output the OP wants. `-t` sorts based on the timestamp, so 5 oct would be before 6 nov but after 6 sept.